# Xterm escape code to remap Page Up (Shift+PageUp) Command in urxvt

Tags: terminal, xterm, urxvt, rxvt

I'd like to bind Ctrl-u to send the Page Up command, but don't know how. 
`URxvt.keysym.Ctrl-u: command:<Shift+PageUp>`

I have bound Ctrl-j to scroll up line by line in urxvt like this:

`URxvt.keysym.Ctrl-j: command:\033]720;1\007`

I know that the code emitted by `PageUp` is `^[[5~`
but the command itself seems to be bound to `Shift+PageUp` in the terminal, and I don't know how to simulate that code.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
URxvt.keysym.Ctrl-u: eval:scroll_up_pages(1)
```